# Prob. 21, Exercises 8.9, in Apostol's CALCULUS vol. II: If the directional derivative of a scalar field vanishes . . .

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

Here is Prob. 21, Exercises 8.9, in the book *Calculus* volume II by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> A set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called *convex* if for every pair of points $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ in $S$ the line segment from $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{b}$ is also in $S$; in other words, $t \mathbf{a} + (1-t) \mathbf{b} \in S$ for each $t$ in the interval $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
>
> (a) Prove that every $n$-ball is convex.
>
> (b) If $f^\prime ( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for every $\mathbf{x}$ in an open convex set $S$ and for every $\mathbf{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $f$ is constant on $S$.

Part (a)

> Let $\mathbf{p}$ be a given point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\delta$ be a given positive real number. Then the $n$-ball $B( \mathbf{p} ; \delta )$ is given by 
>   $$ B( \mathbf{p} ; \delta ) \colon= \{ \ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \colon \ \lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p} \rVert < \delta \ \}, $$
>   where 
>   $$ \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert = \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \left\lvert y_i \right\rvert^2 } $$
>   for any point 
>   $$ \mathbf{y} \colon= \left( y_1, \ldots, y_n \right) $$
>   in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Suppose $\mathbb{a}$ and $\mathbb{b}$ are any two points in $B( \mathbf{p} ; \delta )$ and suppose that $t$ is any real number such that $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Then $\mathbb{a}$ and $\mathbb{b}$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we also have 
>   $$ \lVert \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{p} \rVert < \delta, \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad \lVert \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p} \rVert < \delta. $$
>   So 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \lVert t \mathbf{a} + (1-t) \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p} \rVert &= \lVert t \mathbf{a} + (1-t) \mathbf{b} - [t + (1-t)] \mathbf{p} \rVert \\
> &= \lVert t ( \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{p} ) + (1-t) ( \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p} ) \rVert \\
> &\leq \lVert t ( \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{p} ) \rVert  + \lVert  (1-t) ( \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p} ) \rVert \\
> &= \lvert t \rvert  \lVert  \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{p}  \rVert  + \lvert 1-t \rvert  \lVert  \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p}  \rVert \\
> &=  t \lVert  \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{p}  \rVert  + ( 1-t )  \lVert  \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{p}  \rVert \ [ \mbox{ because } \ t \in [0, 1] \ \mbox{ and } \ 1-t \in [0, 1] \ ] \\
> &< t \delta + (1-t) \delta \\
> &= \delta,
> \end{align}
> $$
>   which shows that the point $t \mathbf{a} + (1-t) \mathbf{b}$ is also in $B( \mathbf{p}; \delta )$. Hence $B( \mathbf{p}; \delta )$ is convex.

Part (b)

> Suppose that $S$ is an open convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose that $f^\prime( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for every $\mathbf{x} \in S$ and for every $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are any two points in $S$. Then, for every $t \in [0, 1]$, the point $t \mathbf{a} + (1-t) \mathbf{b}$ is also in $S$. Now if we put 
>   $$ \mathbf{y} \colon= \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a}, $$
>   then, by the mean-value theorem for scalar fields, we can conclude that,  for some real number $\theta \in (0, 1)$, we have 
>   $$ f( \mathbf{b} ) - f( \mathbf{a} ) = f( \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y} ) - f( \mathbf{a} ) = f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + \theta \mathbf{y} ; \mathbf{y} ). \tag{1}   $$
>   Now 
>   $$ \mathbf{a} + \theta \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{a} + \theta (\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a} ) = \theta \mathbf{b} + (1- \theta) \mathbf{a} \in S, $$
>   and thus 
>   $$ f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + \theta \mathbf{y} ; \mathbf{y} ) = 0,  $$
>   by our hypothesis. Therefore (1) gives 
>   $$  f( \mathbf{b} ) = f( \mathbf{a} ) $$
>   for any two points $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ in $S$. Hence $f$ is constant on set $S$.

Is this proof correct? If so, then do we really need our set $S$ to be *open* in $\mathbb{R}^n$? If not, then where is it that I'm going wrong?

Comment: $S$ is required to be open because you need an open set to define $f'$.

Comment: @Javi Here is Apostol's definition of the directional derivative: 

 Given a scalar field $f \colon S \to \mathbb{R}$, where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathbf{a}$ be an interior point of $S$ and let $\mathbf{y}$ be an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The _derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf{a}$ with respect to $\mathbf{y}$_ is denoted by the symbol $f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y})$ and is defined by the equation 
$$ f^\prime(\mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f( \mathbf{a} + h \mathbf{y} ) - f( \mathbf{a})}{h}  $$
when the limit on the right exists.